# SQLite Error 21 . "Misuse at line ... "

Tags: android, sqlite, mono

I'm using this code to store SQLite DB to sdcard location (location on device /mnt/sdcard/MiniMate ):

```
string libraryPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;            
libraryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(libraryPath, "MiniMate");
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(libraryPath)) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(libraryPath);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
```

It works perfect when I using deploying from Visual studio to device; However if I  create .apk and install it on device it gives me an error "21". Looks like it's not permissions to do something with DB, I have "Constraint" error when I trying to insert something in DB.

Does somebody know this issue?
I'm not looking to move DB to different default location, Thank you!

My Manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" package="com.prismvs.minimate" android:versionCode="14" android:versionName="14">
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="12" android:minSdkVersion="12" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="MiniMate">
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this a few days ago and spent so much time for find a problem because I moved in wrong dirrection, so I want to share this experience maybe it will help somebody to fix their issues with SQLite + Mono for Android:

1. I had project what main app and user libraried in different project (common cross platform project)
2. SQLite was using in user library not in main application project
3. When I build Release (apk) for Google Play and install it on Android device I had error log: E/SQLiteLog(32375): (1) near ")": syntax error
   E/SQLiteLog(32375): (21) API called with NULL prepared statement
   E/SQLiteLog(32375): (21) misuse at line 63243 of [00bb9c9ce4]
   It was not happen for debug version, so what I did for fixinfg this problem:
   On Visual studion project properties -> Mono Android  Options -> Linking: I set "SDK assemblies Only" instead of "SDK and User assemblies"
   This error is disappear.